# Node.js then is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on an open source project where we want to use a local json file as a database. We decided to use this package to handle the getters and setters (https://github.com/typicode/lowdb).

I've copied their example file that uses express, but I get the following error: `db.defaults(...).write(...).then is not a function`

This is my Server.js file:

```
import express from 'express'
import session from 'express-session'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import promisify from 'es6-promisify'
import cors from 'cors'
import low from 'lowdb'
import fileAsync from 'lowdb/lib/storages/file-async'

import defaultdb from './models/Pages'

import routes from './routes/index.js'

const app = express();

const db = low('./core/db/index.json')

app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/', routes);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1337);

db.defaults(defaultdb).write().then(() => {
    app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
      console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
    });
});
```

I made sure to use stage-0 with babel, hoping it would fix this. But not avail. Any help would be great!

Comment: how sure are you db.defaults is wrapped in a promise ?. I kind of suspect db.defaults is a writable stream and writable streams don't have a then method

Comment: It means that the value returned by `.write()` doesn't have a property `.then`. That's not something that Babel can fix. You have to read the API documentation to see what value it actually returns. You seem to expect it to return a promise, but why? Did you look at the documentation / the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb#api) `.write()` only returns a promise if you use an async storage method. You have to do more than just require `fileAsync` to get that to work ;)

```
const db = low('./core/db/index.json', { storage: fileAsync })
```

Comment: Oops forgot this. It fixed it, but now my server keeps restarting because of changes...